# Python while loop query

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I need a little help understanding this piece of code, the result generated by the code is:
4 3 2 0
Why is 1 not being printed? Thanks in advance. here is the code:

```
n = 3

while n > 0:
    print(n + 1, end = " ")
    n -= 1
else:
    print(n, end = "")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n=3 -> prints n+1 i.e. 4
n-1 = 2
n=2 -> prints 3
n-1 = 1
n=1 -> prints 2
n-1 = 0
n=0 -> goes to else statement as while condition is not satisfied. prints 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you print `n+1` every time in the loop, then outside the loop you print `n`. If you print `n+1` the output will be `4 3 2 1`:

```py
n = 3
while n > 0:
    print(n + 1, end = " ")
    n -= 1
else:
    print(n + 1, end = "")
```